# PHP: Getting text to appear (or disappear) when variable equals product name

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm working locally on a small PHP store. All custom code I inherited from someone else. So in the cart, the product name appears via a variable set like the following.

```
<p>Today's charge will appear as ${{cart['main_product']['productPrice']}} on your credit card statement.</p>
```

So `${{cart['main_product']['productPrice']}}` is replaced by the actual name of the product ordered. This all works.

So the client has one product that has additional text for terms and conditions and they only should show up if this one product is in the cart. So I tried a couple of different PHP functions and the code goes away but on all products. Not just the one.

The text is set up a string called `$trial_msg`. That does work but I'm puzzled how to best display it as a function. Here's what I currently have.

```
<?php
    $productname = "{{cart['main_product']['productName']}}";
    if ($productname == 'Razor (Trial)') {
        echo $trial_msg; 
    }
?>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<?php
    if ({{cart['productName']}} == 'Razor (Trial)') {
        echo $trial_msg; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$productname = $cart['main_product']['productName']`? Your `$productname = "{{cart['main_product']['productName']}}";` will set it to a _string_ which will never match `'Razor (Trial)'`. Are you using a templating engine to make `${{cart['main_product']['productPrice']}}` work?

Comment: Have you tried`$productname = $cart['main_product']['productName']`? Like @brombeer mentioned, `"{{cart['main_product']['productName']}}"` looks like some template engine code that wouldn't work directly in PHP like this. Additionally, if you do `var_dump($productname);` after setting the value, you can see what it's being set to.

Comment: Tried that and thanks for the var_dump idea, but the results came back as NULL.

Comment: So I found that if I do $productname = "{{cart['main_product']['productName']}}"; it will return in the var dump the following "string(39) "My Perfect Golden Gadgets Store Plus - Razor Trial"" However, if I try using if ($productname == and anything after it, the text still does not display.